# Como posso manipular CSS do elemento pai ao elemento clicado?

Tags: jquery, css

Preciso alterar meu código de forma que ao clicar em uma div, a div pai mude seu css. Por exemplo eu clico em um input dentro da div, e a div pai muda o seu css.

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tel, .email, #nome, .col-lg-6").click(function(){
      // A div é a com a classe .col-lg-6
      // O código que sei é esse $(this).css({"background-color":"red"}); mas preciso de um código que mude o css daquela div, que pelo qual possui o objeto que foi clicado.
  }
}
```

```js
$(".tel, .email, #nome, .col-lg-6").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");// código ao ser alterado
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="email">Email</div>
<div class="teste1">teste1</div>
<div class="email">email</div>
<div class="teste2">teste2</div>
<div class="tel">Tel</div>
<div class="teste3">teste3</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="email">Email</div>
<div class="teste1">teste1</div>
<div class="email">email</div>
<div class="teste2">teste2</div>
<div class="tel">Tel</div>
<div class="teste3">teste3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acessar o elemento pai você pode utilizar o [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) do `Jquery` para pegar a `div` "pai" da clicada e assim manipular seu `CSS`.

```
$(this).parent("div").css("background-color","red");
```

Segue abaixo exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(".tel, .email, #nome, .col-lg-6").click(function(){
    $(this).parent("div").css("background-color","red");
});
```

```css
#div1{
  background-color:blue;
}

#div2{
  background-color:green;
}

.email {
  width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:orange;
}

.teste1 {
  width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6" id="div1">
  <div class="email">Email</div>
  <div class="teste1">teste1</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="col-lg-6"  id="div2">
  <div class="email">Email</div>
  <div class="teste1">teste1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Na verdade não é esse o problema. Eu preciso que ao clicar em um dos itens uma div que encorpora todos, mude o css.

Comment: Não consegui entender, tente especificar exatamente quais elementos deseja modificar após um determinada div ser clicada. Exemplo.: ao clicar em um div da classe x desejo que todos os elementos dessa classe sejam modificados.

Comment: Ao clicar em um dos elementos das divs com a classe "col-lg-6", aquela div que contém o elemento que foi clicado seja alterado o css dela.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o que quer, precisa selecionar o item pai com a função [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) quando clica nos elementos filhos:

```js
//para pegar o click nos filhos da div
$('.tel, .email, .nome').click(function(){
  $('.col-lg-6').css('background-color', 'lightblue'); //volta o padrão
  $(this).parent('div').css('background-color', 'blue');
});

//para pegar o click na div
$('.col-lg-6').click(function(){
  $('.col-lg-6').css('background-color', 'lightblue'); //volta o padrão
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

```css
.col-lg-6{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="text" class="tel">
  <input type="text" class="email">
  <input type="text" class="nome">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="text" class="tel">
  <input type="text" class="email">
  <input type="text" class="nome">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="text" class="tel">
  <input type="text" class="email">
  <input type="text" class="nome">
</div>
```

Comment: São várias divs com a mesma classe. Se eu usasse esse código ele mudaria o css de todas as divs com a classe "col-lg-6".

Comment: O que preciso, é que de várias divs aquela que em um elemento dela for clicado, apenas aquela div que possui aquele elemento clicado, mude o seu css, ou seja, tenho várias divs com a mesma classe, e cada div tem um mesmo elemento com name diferente. Preciso que apenas aquela div que possui o elemento clicado altere seu css.

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja agora

Answer (score -1):

Use o `parent()` do Jquery com o seletor da classe 'mae' (`.col-lg-6`) que vc diz, e o `focus()` ao invés de `click()` já que se trata de inputs:

```js
$('.tel, .email, .nome').focus(function(){
  $(this).parent(".col-lg-6").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
.col-lg-6{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<input type="text" class="tel">
<input type="text" class="email">
<input type="text" id="nome">
<div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
<input type="text" class="tel">
<input type="text" class="email">
<input type="text" class="nome">
<div>
```